# I was trying to run a simple program in visual studio code but I run into this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Is there anything wrong with the program or do some changes have to be made in the system settings?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOyUT.png)
[Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: working fine on my side!! just a suggestion don't give variable name `sum` as it is built-in data type in python.

Comment: Okay, this is a notable point. Thankyou Yash!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The codes and the error are different. Are you sure you ran the current code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and also this post explaining [why you should not post images of code in you questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/389289).

Comment: I can't post images right now I am new to StackOverflow I have to reach some level for posting the picture here

Answer (score 0):

Remove `&` at the beggining and `/` at the end of your path:

[image]

Comment: I hate to say it but the truth is this sort of thing basically never stops happening no matter how good you get at coding.